# If conditionals with not and startswith()

Tags: python

I'm trying to add some manual garbage collection at the end of my script, but for some reason when I iterate through `dir()` it is still picking up names that start with `"blob"` even though I've tried to specify not to do so. Reason for doing so is that trying to delete dataframes through `del globals()[name]` causes errors. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#Initializing  data frames
blob_data_frame = None
blob_data_frame1 = None
blob_data_frame2 = None

...


del blob_data_frame # This one will always not be None
if blob_data_frame1 is not None:
    del blob_data_frame1
if blob_data_frame2 is not None:
    del blob_data_frame2

for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_') or not name.startswith('blob'): <- PROBLEM
        del globals()[name]

for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_') or not name.startswith('blob'):
        del locals()[name]
```

Comment: *All* names either don't start with "_" or don't start with "blob". You want `and` there.

Comment: @kindall Oops, yeah I think I'd had it as ```and``` before and it wasn't working, which made me change it to ```or``` just to see. I'm going to make sure and update you soon.

Comment: Also, I should mention that `startswith()` can take a tuple of prefixes. `if not name.startswith(("_", "blob"))` ...

Comment: @kindall Thank you, that is useful information. Also changing the ```or``` to ```and``` was actually the problem. I still get errors, but that's because there is one more case I have to account for. I mistakenly thought there was something wrong with the statement and didn't realize what the actual problem was. That's pretty embarrassing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you want to delete all variables where the name does not start with `"_"`, **AND** the name does not start with `"blob"`. However, your code is deleting variables where the names do not start with `"_"` **OR** names that do not start with `"blob"`.

The difference between the "and" and the "or" is significant here. In the "and" case, the variable name has to meet **both** conditions. In the "or" case, though, the variable name can meet **either *OR* both** conditions - meaning that if the variable starts with `"_"`, for example, then that means it doesn't start with `"blob"`, so the `if` statement would evaluate to `True`.

Example:

```
not startswith("_") OR not startswith("blob"):
startswith("_")
-> True
startswith("blob")
-> False
-> not True OR not False
-> False OR True
-> True

not startswith("_") AND not startswith("blob"):
startswith("_")
-> True
startswith("blob")
-> False
-> not True AND not False
-> False AND True
-> False
```